# How to remove “no cents” when spelling out cents less dollar figures in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Currently, I am spelling out dollar values using a module from the Microsoft support website. Here is the link http://support.microsoft.com/KB/213360

I am able to spell out dollar values in Excel perfectly. But what I don't want is when it spells out "no cents". So, let's say if I wanted to spell out `24030`. It would say `Twenty Four Thousand Thirty Dollars and no cents`. I want Excel to spell out the cents value only when it is present.

I would really appreciate if someone could help me in this. Thanks a bunch in advance.

I apologize in advance if this question has already been asked, but in my defense I was unable to find the right answer for it. Hopefully some one can help me on this issue.

Answer (score 4):

It is a case statement that selects which option is given based off of the criteria presented. For cents, if it is presented with a blank string, it then chooses " and No Cents". In this instance, just change what it provides to a blank string:

```
Select Case Cents
        Case ""
            Cents = ""
        Case "One"
            Cents = " and One Cent"
        Case Else
            Cents = " and " & Cents & " Cents"
End Select
```